# Could this union give unexpected values on a little endian machine

Tags: c, endianness, unions

Could this union give me problem on a little endian machine

```
union {
    struct {  
        uint32_t min[4];        
        uint32_t max[4];        
    } x1;

    struct {  
        uint64_t min[2];       
        uint64_t max[2];       
    } x1_64;
} u;
```

If i store values using struct x1 and retrieve using x1_64 would the endianness come into play and return unexpected values??

Comment: I don't understand. If you have two 32-bit minimum values, how are they supposed to correspond to a single 64-bit minimum value? How do you intend to use this union?

Comment: Any reason not to use a native 64-bit type if possible to prevent worrying about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "yes". On a little endian machine you have to store x1 in reverse order. See the following picture:

[image]

It means that the low part of x1_64.min[0] should be stored as x.min[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMdgJ.jpg)] and the high part as x1.min[0]. On a big endian machine you do not have to do this.

(n.b.: I'm always confused with little and big, so excuse me if it should read "big endian")

Answer (score 1):

On a little-endian machine `((unsigned char *)u.min[0]` will point to the least significant byte of both `u.min` values and `u.min[0]` (of type `uint32_t`) will contain the lowest 32 bits of the 64 value.

On a big-endian machine `((unsigned char *)u.min[0])` will contain the most significant byte of both `u.min` values and `u.min[0]` will contain the highest 32 bits.

So endianness matters as usual.